# access fonts installed through LaTeX with XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, helvetica

I don't have e.g. Helvetica, yet would like to use its clone that can be used with `pdflatex`, but instead use it with `xelatex`. I have tried

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{helvet}
\newfontfamily{\phv}{Helvetica}
```

Which tells me fontspec can't find Helvetica.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\arial}{Arial}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\arial}
```

Which works, since I'm on a windows machine and arial is installed.

```
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{helvet}
\newfontfamily{\phv}{Helvetica}
```

Which works with `pdflatex`. Switching back

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\usepackage{helvet}
\setsansfont{Helvetica} % <-- doesn't work, since I don't have the font installed on my system
%\newfontfamily{\phv}{Helvetica}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\section{first section}

some text which should be in helvetica

\end{document}
```

MWE that I wish to be working:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{helvet}
\newfontfamily{\phv}{Helvetica}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\phv}

\begin{document}

\section{first section}

some text which should not be in helvetica

\end{document}
```

[I'm sorry, but I won't take the time to get into LuaTeX atm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198897/117274). I'm at a loss as to what I should try, and how, and in which order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the clone TeX Gyre Heros:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
\section{first section}

some text which should be in helvetica

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So it isn't possible to use fonts installed in the texmf tree with xelatex? Only fonts installed system-wise?

Comment: I'm sorry, the question is way too complicated for what I want to achieve. I'm just insterested in accessing fonts not installed on my machine, but in the tex distro, using xelatex. Is that possible?

Comment: tex gyre heros is in the texmf tree. One my system in `texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyreheros-regular.otf`. If you are on linux you need to enable the name search for xetex (https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-340003.4.4), or use file names instead. Or simply use lualatex which will work out-of-box.