# IEEEtran: Getting fonts "right" with lualatex

Tags: luatex, fontspec, ieeetran

I know that `IEEEtran` is basically pdflatex only.
However, I would prefer using `lualatex` but it gives me a couple of font warnings for this snippet:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

%\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc} % does not help
\usepackage{fontspec,mathtools,unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}


\begin{document}
    bla
\end{document}
```

the warnings are:

```
Font shape `TU/ptm/m/n' undefined(Font) using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead
Font shape `TU/ptm/bx/n' undefined(Font) using `TU/ptm/m/n' instead
Font shape `TU/ptm/m/it' undefined(Font) using `TU/ptm/m/n' instead
Font shape `TU/ptm/bx/it' undefined(Font) using `TU/ptm/bx/n' instead
```

I tried the solutions suggested in [How to compile IEEE Access templates with XeLaTeX with fontspec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418954/how-to-compile-ieee-access-templates-with-xelatex-with-fontspec?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Do I need to use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} if I use lualatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412757/do-i-need-to-use-usepackaget1fontenc-if-i-use-lualatex) without success.

Edit: For the conference, only the PDFs are uploaded. No sources are shared with the organizers/IEEE.

Comment: the only (or at leat usual) reason to use a publisher class such as ieeetran is for journal publications, and if the journal is using pdftex then submitting an article using fontspec isn't going to work?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, its for a conference, I guess they just employ certain font checks that I want to pass :-)

Comment: exactly but if they want to produce the conference proceedings and they use pdftex for that, what can they do with one paper using fontspec?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I, naively, assumed that I can ask fontspec to use exactly the same fonts, or are there more issues than that? (The conference does not get the sources, only the compiled PDF)

Comment: if they are producing a combined proceedings including all the papers in to a single pdftex run that is trivial if everyone uses the specified document class as you simply ignore the  per article preambles and run the articles together. If you supply a luatex-only document it is like supplying a Word document and totally breaks the workflow.  It is probably easy to avoid the warning you post, but I would not be surprised if the resulting paper fails any submission guidelines. **Oh** just saw you said they only want the pdf, odd, in that case my objection doesn't apply.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle maybe I failed to supply some important information: For the conference, only the final PDFs are uploaded. They don't ask/get the sources. Do still the same issues arise there?

Comment: No if they only want the pdf that's different ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the same 8bit fonts as pdftex, but just use luatex (eg to use some Lua features) you can revert to OT1 or T1 before loading the class, eg

```
\RequirePackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}


\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}
    bla
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It leaves only a single warning if I use `\RequirePackage[OT1]{fontenc}` before `documentclass` in my snippet above: Font shape `TU/ptm/m/n' undefined(Font) using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead

Comment: I get no font warning with the posted example on texlive 2019. I do get one warning `Non-PDF special ignored!{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/upd
map/pdftex.map}]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  see my answer, \pdfoutput is not defined. And I see a warning about fonts.

Comment: True, the warning is due to `unicode-math` I guess. There any way to still use it?

Comment: if you use unicode math you'd need a times-like math font, stix or stix2 I suppose? the warnings are probably just in the setup and don't reflect anything in the actual document as long as you have everything consistently defined by the end of the preamble.

Comment: This ended up skipping non-ascii chars, and I found out that putting the extra `\setmainfont` found in [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198833/64362) answer helped.

Comment: As @MayeulC has rightly said, adding `\RequirePackage[OT1]{fontenc}` (or `\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}`) garbles Unicode characters in the input, such as copyright symbols, en-dashes and non-breaking spaces. `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}` leads to infinite compilation in my case. Any case we can get the same result as in `pdflatex` in terms of (absence of) font warnings and Unicode input? I thought fonts and unicode support were one of the strengths of `lualatex` ;)

Comment: @bers yes unicode fonts is one of the strength of luatex but this question asks (for some reason) how to disable that and use 8bit tex fonts. The question is how to use classic tex fonts with luatex, it's then not that surprising that unicpde is broken (use luainputenc package if you want similar behaviour to inputenc with pdftex)

Comment: `\RequirePackage[utf8]{luainputenc}` is working, thank you! "for some reason" is easy to explain: some people (including me) want to use `IEEEtran`, including the fonts it proposes, with `lualatex`. If there was another way of getting `TU/ptm/m/n` in `lualatex`, I'd happily use that, but well, I only found this question and this answer.

Comment: @bers ptm is just times roman (but usually configured to use a clone so it can use embedded fonts) so the usual way would be `\setmainfont{Times Roman}` (or Times New Roman or TeX Gyre Termes or whatever clone you wanted to embed.

Answer (score 0):

The warnings are in the middle of the class loading. The class tries to use a bold and italic font to set some font dimens. Imho you can simply ignore it, fontspec will set its own fontdimens anyway when you load TeX Gyre Termes.

But you should add before \documentclass this so that the class correctly tests for pdf output:

```
  \let\pdfoutput \outputmode
```

Comment: Does that mean that in the final PDF the correct font is used (and the PDF checker used by  IEEE won't complain) ?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by the "correct font". It will use the `texgyretermes-regular.otf` and this is certainly not the same font a standard IEEE document uses, so if they check for the font they won't be happy.