# Text not bold in IEEEtran paper (LuaLaTeX / Debian Linux)

Tags: fonts, luatex, ieeetran, abstract, debian

I'm writing a paper that uses an IEEEtran layout, but for some reason it doesn't seem to be loading the fonts correctly. The abstract should be bold, but it currently isn't, for example.

I'm currently running LuaLaTeX using the following latexmk command:

```
latexmk -pdf -bibtex-cond -lualatex -use-make -interaction=nonstopmode
```

Am I forgetting to install something? I have tried installing all the tex packages that had anything font related in the name to no avail.

Is there a way for me to debug and check what is happening?

Here's the minimal example:

```
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\title{The title}

\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Place\\
University of Place\\
Place\\
Email: email@example.com}
}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \begin{abstract}
        This should be bold. It currently isn't.
    \end{abstract}
    \begin{IEEEkeywords}
        key words here
    \end{IEEEkeywords}

    \section{Introduction}
        blah blah blah
\end{document}
```

Ps.: I've seen a bunch of related questions, but they all were related to languages that use different scripts than latin, which is not my case.

[image: Picture of the document]

Comment: the class isn't meant for luatex, it forces ptm as font family and then all sort of substituations kick in.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484771/ieeetran-getting-fonts-right-with-lualatex

Comment: The manual has an example: https://bigdataieee.org/BigData2022/files/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can revert to a setup that's mostly similar to `pdflatex` with two additions:

```latex
\renewcommand{\encodingdefault}{OT1}           % <----
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}                 % <----

\title{The title}

\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Place\\
University of Place\\
Place\\
Email: email@example.com}
}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \begin{abstract}
        This should be bold. It currently isn't.
    \end{abstract}
    \begin{IEEEkeywords}
        key words here
    \end{IEEEkeywords}

    \section{Introduction}
        blah blah blah
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if you don't have special needs to run LuaLaTeX, avoid it for submissions to IEEE journals.

Comment: I didn't had any special reason to be using LuaLaTeX on this specific paper and I have followed your advice on switching back to pdfLaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

If you must employ LuaLaTeX rather than pdfLaTeX -- say, because you have some nifty Lua code you wish to employ -- I suggest you add the following instructions to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmainfont{Stix Two Text}
  \setmathfont{Stix Two Math}
\fi
```

Doing this will generate the following output:

[image]