# Tabular and SI \unit comand \uA giving a weird t

Tags: texstudio, siunitx

I just stumbled upon this weird problem using `siunitx`. I'm doing my report (mandatory in IEEE style), and it seem the micro prefix is giving me this strange t, inside a `tabular` environment.
I specified in the preamble how I wanted the `\per` option to be like, as a division line.

On W10 through texstudio and XeLaTeX

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \caption{the caption}
    \label{tab:ref-of-my-table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ll*{1}{S}l}
        \toprule
        {A} &   {B} & {Value} & {Unit}\\
        \midrule
        AA  &   & 0.46  & \unit{\volt} \\
        BB  &   & 0.6 & \unit{\volt} \\
        EE  &   & 115 & \unit{\uA \per  \volt \squared} \\
        GG  &   & 40  & \unit{\micro \ampere \per  \volt \squared} \\
        Slew rate   &   &   & \\
        Voltage swing IN    &   &   &    \\
        Voltage swing OUT   &   &   &    \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

and the output is

[image]

The document and preamble

```
\documentclass[conference,a4paper,10pt,twocolumn,twoside]{IEEEtran}
%\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500       % IEEE 2 col break multiline equations
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
    \usepackage{subcaption} % 
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{subfloat}
    \usepackage{placeins}   % 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{./images}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        inter-unit-product =\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},
        display-per-mode = fraction ,
        inline-per-mode = symbol,       %% Division is "/"
        table-number-alignment = center,
        table-figures-integer = 1,
        table-figures-decimal = 2,
    }
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\begin{document}

%% Some IEEE set up, title, author, abstract
%% Usual template stuff for IEEEtran type of document

\section{my first section}

%% Some paragraphs about my report

%% The table in question
\begin{table}[h]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \caption{the caption}
    \label{tab:ref-of-my-table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ll*{1}{S}l}
        \toprule
        {A} &   {B} & {Value} & {Unit}\\
        \midrule
        AA  &   & 0.46  & \unit{\volt} \\
        BB  &   & 0.6 & \unit{\volt} \\
        EE  &   & 115 & \unit{\uA \per  \volt \squared} \\
        GG  &   & 40  & \unit{\micro \ampere \per  \volt \squared} \\
        Slew rate   &   &   & \\
        Voltage swing IN    &   &   &    \\
        Voltage swing OUT   &   &   &    \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

%% bib file still need to be imported

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce with `\documentclass{IEEEtran}` but that worked fine and shows μ characters. So please edit your question with the _full_ code that produces the wrong output.

Comment: Put the full code.

Comment: Also for me your code worked fine and shows μ characters. It is perfect.

Comment: That's really weird...... 
I've also cleaned the auxiliary files anr recompiled, still that weird shaped t

Comment: You shouldn't use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with XeLaTeX, remove that and the output is fine.

Comment: Yep, now the \mu is showing, but the abstract is not in bold anymore. Thanks

Comment: That is a known issue with IEEEtran on XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495490/text-not-bold-in-ieeetran-paper-lualatex-debian-linux. A solution is to load the fonts via `fontspec` instead of via a package, so remove also `textcomp` and `pifont` and use something like `\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}` to get a Times New Roman variant (TeX Gyre in this case, if you don't have that font installed then there are a few other options like Liberation Serif or FreeSerif).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With XeLaTeX, you should *not* use `fontenc` and `textcomp`.

If you want to comply with the standard Times font of IEEEtran, you can load `newtx`.

Also `subcaption` is *not* compatible with `IEEEtran` and you should not load it. The `subfloat` package does not do “subfloats” in the same sense as `subcaption`. If you really need subfloats, do

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

The consequence of loading `caption` (or `subcaption`) is that captions will not be in the `IEEEtran` style.

With the corrections:

```
\documentclass[conference,a4paper,10pt,twocolumn,twoside]{IEEEtran}
%\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
%\usepackage{subcaption} % not compatible with IEEEtran
%\usepackage{float} % useless
%\usepackage{subfloat} % do you really need it?
%\usepackage{placeins} % useless in two-column format
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{./images}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs

\usepackage{newtx}

\sisetup{
  inter-unit-product =\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},
  display-per-mode = fraction ,
  inline-per-mode = symbol,       %% Division is "/"
  table-number-alignment = center,
  table-figures-integer = 1,
  table-figures-decimal = 2,
}

\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500       % IEEE 2 col break multiline equations

\begin{document}

%% Some IEEE set up, title, author, abstract
%% Usual template stuff for IEEEtran type of document

\section{my first section}

%% Some paragraphs about my report

%% The table in question
\begin{table}[htp]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \caption{the caption}
    \label{tab:ref-of-my-table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ll*{1}{S}l}
        \toprule
        {A} &   {B} & {Value} & {Unit}\\
        \midrule
        AA  &   & 0.46  & \unit{\volt} \\
        BB  &   & 0.6 & \unit{\volt} \\
        EE  &   & 115 & \unit{\uA \per  \volt \squared} \\
        GG  &   & 40  & \unit{\micro \ampere \per  \volt \squared} \\
        Slew rate   &   &   & \\
        Voltage swing IN    &   &   &    \\
        Voltage swing OUT   &   &   &    \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

%% bib file still need to be imported

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are my hero. Is there somewhere a quick guide about the priority of packages declaration, and compatibility between latex compiler and/or document class??

Comment: @Fr3d The general rule is to load *only* the packages you really need in the document. Custom classes such as `IEEEtran` often are incompatible with `caption` and you'll find a warning about an unsupported class in the log file.